# Warmup Jetty handler code

Tags: servlets, jetty

I need to warmup a jetty application. I would like to send requests to my handler class but I want not able to find easy way to create http request/response objects (in request I need only a few attributes like uri, query params, body). Is there any utility class to build them (don't want to have mocks in production code).
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not just using URLConnection to issue a normal HTTP request into the servlet?

Comment: Thanks, @JoakimErdfelt, it solves the issue.

Comment: Heh, I was just asking as I wanted to understand your situation better.  Glad I accidentally helped.